# Prometheus/PromQL/Grafana: Substraction when the right side range vector is potentially non-existent

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have two counter metrics: `always_exists` and `sometimes_exists`.

I want to receive a result vector from the substraction `always_exists - sometimes_exists`, even if the metric `sometimes_exists` doesn't exist (i.e. the query returns nothing). I'd like the result to be equal to `always_exists - 0` in that case. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
(always_exists - sometimes_exists) or (always_exists unless sometimes_exists)
```

It uses `or` and `unless` operators. See more details on these operators at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators

P.S. The query can be simplified to `sum(always_exists, -sometimes_exists)` in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics), since [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) supports multiple arguments in aggregate functions such as `sum`. (I'm the core developer of VictoriaMetrics)

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how often I've scrolled past this section in the docs without figuring out this combination of operators.